# Improved file download time in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, download

I am doing a function that compresses a list of images and downloads them. I had a problem where the download took quite a while. How can I improve download speed?

My code

api.php

```
Route::post('/download-images', [DownloadController::class, 'downloadImages'])->name('api.download.images');
```

controller

```
public function downloadImages(Request $request)
{
    $zipFileName = $this->service->downloadImages($request);

    return response()->download($zipFileName, null, ['Content-Type: application/octet-stream','Content-Length: '. filesize($zipFileName)])->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
}
```

service

```
public function downloadImages(Request $request)
{
    $imageUrls = $request->get('images');
    $type = $request->get('type') ?? 'images';

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zipFileName = $type . '.zip';

    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    if ($zip->open($zipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) === true) {
        foreach ($imageUrls as $imageUrl) {
            $imageContent = file_get_contents($imageUrl);
            $filename = basename($imageUrl);
            $zip->addFromString($filename, $imageContent);
        }
        $zip->close();

        return $zipFileName;
    }

    return $zipFileName;
}
```

At client. I call ajax

```
function downloadImages(eleClass) {
    $("div.spanner").addClass("show");
    $("div.overlay").addClass("show");
    const imageLinks = [];
    $('ul.'+ eleClass +' li img').each(function() {
        var imageLink = $(this).attr('src');
        imageLinks.push(imageLink);
    });
    if (imageLinks.length == 0) {
        $("div.spanner").removeClass("show");
        $("div.overlay").removeClass("show");

        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/download-images',
      method: 'POST',
      data: { images: imageLinks },
      xhrFields: {
        responseType: 'blob' // Set the response type to 'blob'
      },
      success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        // Handle success, e.g., show a success message
        console.log('Images downloaded successfully.');
        // Create a temporary anchor element
        var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(data); // Create a Blob URL for the response
        downloadLink.download = eleClass + '.zip'; // Set the desired file name

        // Programmatically trigger the download
        downloadLink.click();
        $("div.spanner").removeClass("show");
        $("div.overlay").removeClass("show");
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        // Handle error, e.g., display an error message
        console.error('Error downloading images:', error);
        $("div.spanner").removeClass("show");
        $("div.overlay").removeClass("show");
      }
   });
}
```

I watched it on the browser and it took a long time to "Content Download"
[image]

I am looking for a solution to improve file download speed. Or another solution for compressing the list of image links and downloads

Comment: How much data are you downloading?  Networks are not infinitely fast.  If you're on a 10Mbps link and you are fetching 100MB of images, then 70 seconds is entirely reasonable.

Comment: my zip file has almost 700KB. I tried to change the wifi network or use another computer but the result is still no improvement

Comment: Is this when you are testing the page locally? What's your setup?

Comment: @apokryfos i am testing in testing env. I deploy page on aws with 2 pod

Comment: @TimRoberts my zip file has almost 700KB. I tried to change the wifi network or use another computer but the result is still no improvement

Comment: Is it slow locally, on AWS or on both? Can you also try using the URL directly rather than via AJAX in case `createObjectURL` is what is slow?

Comment: @apokryfos on both, As far as I can see, it's slower on aws than on local. Ok, I am trying use URL directly

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding header and callback function to delete the file after sending and it improved quite a bit, about 12s

controller

```
$zipFileName = $this->service->downloadImages($request);

// Set the headers for the download
$headers = [
   'Content-Type' => 'application/zip',
   'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . $zipFileName . '"',
];

// Delete the temporary file after download
register_shutdown_function(function () use ($zipFileName) {
    unlink($zipFileName);
});

// Return the download response
return response()->download($zipFileName, null, $headers);
```